# Stream data for users

Tags: mysql, ruby, node.js, linux

I want to build a server that could stream data from multiple endpoints simultaneously for analytics purposes.

Scenario:
users registered on our platform will provide credentials of their IoT device. E.g https://stream.example.com/user1 & https://stream.example.com/user2

Our responsibility is to monitor the device log and status in order to generate reports.

Questions:
Since each stream will keep a HTTP connection open, how can I make a node.js or ruby app to open serval HTTP stream?

Comment: Do you want your server to get data from your devices and mux that into a single stream?

Comment: Is it possible? I'm not familiar with data streaming. Please suggest a way to do it. Thanks

Comment: Well yes. One of the cases I did have in mind when I wrote Scramjet... I'll write an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your case I'd root for node.js too - keeping an open connection works well in asynchronous frameworks and Ruby doesn't seem very fit (but then I'm not much into Ruby).

Using [Scramjet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scramjet) this would be pretty easy, but keep in mind that both parties have to keep an open connection anyway, so it's not the node app itself. I understand that your case is that your node app will actively open connections to a number of devices with the given credentials and these devices will then respond with a never ending stream over http, a bit like Twitter's streaming API's... then the implementation would look a little like this:

```
new scramjet.MultiStream(devicesList.map(
     (device) => request.post(device, credentials)
          .pipe(new StringStream())
          .split("\r?\n") // or however you'd read your messages
          .parse(JSON.parse) // or however you'd parse your data
          .assign({deviceId: device.id}) // you'll probably need this
))
.mux(/* optionally an ordering function */)
// above there's a single stream with all the logs from all your devices.
```

If this is the other way round and the devices are calling the server, then take a look at [scramjet-http-uristream](https://github.com/MichalCz/scramjet-http-uristream) or [scramjet-http-post](https://github.com/MichalCz/scramjet-http-post) - it's a simple sever that just streams all uri's or posts that are posted to a server.

I hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

I feel that the CPU may not be the bottleneck because most of the time your application is just handling IO (streaming network data to files). However, you should consider your bandwidth and you'll have to scale out when the bandwidth become the bottleneck. In such case, a traditional reverse proxy won't help. You have to do some DNS tricks such as round robin DNS, to dispatch your clients evenly to your servers, and let them connect to your servers DIRECTLY.

I suggest not to use a database to store those logs. Plain text files will be good enough. You can create a crontab job to periodically parse those files and update database if necessary.

I recommend not to use Ruby. Node.js is good in this situation due to its async IO, which allows you to handle thousands of such connections in just one thread.

Comment: Sorry. My previous question is a bit unclear. I have updated my question. Could you please check if you have any idea on that?